# Merge reversed linestring in correct order in postGIS

Tags: postgis, sql

I want to merge linestring in the correct order in postGIS, but sometime they are reversed so something like this :

```
select astext(linemerge(ST_union(
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(3 3, 2 2)'),
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(1 1, 2 2)'))));
```

returns this :

```
"LINESTRING(1 1,2 2,3 3)"
```

But I want this :

```
"LINESTRING(3 3, 2 2, 1 1)"
```

I really don't know what to do.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to reverse a geometry you can just use `ST_Reverse` (returns the geometry with vertex order reversed).

If the problem is you want to keep some arbitrary order, I don't think you can do it using `ST_Union` (the definition for `ST_Union` being *point set union*, as in ordering is not guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

Give it to diciu. I just want to add an example:

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Reverse(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(3 3, 2 2)')));
```